# How to Open a outlook mail from apex code

Tags: email, outlook, salesforce, protocols, apex-code

i am a Salesforce developer. I have an application by which i can read mail after click on a row in a table that is in a Visualforce page.
Now i would add another enhancement : i want click on a row and open an outlook mail that is on my pc. Is this  possible?
Does exist an outlook protocol by which i can navigate to a mail ?

Thanks to all,

F.P.

Answer (score 1):

You can create in your VP a link to outlook mail like this:

```
<a href='Outlook:00000000CC63759F18171E46835E96E44971FDFB07006446′>Email subject here
```

Set **Outlook** as **protocol** and *link* de **GUID** (Globally Unique Identifier).

Read [here](http://www.davidtan.org/create-hyperlinks-to-outlook-messages-folders-contacts-events/) for more info

Comment: With this code i'm able to open outlook, but not to open the mail. Have you some advices?

Comment: Any outlook's mail has an ID called GUID, when you set href using Outlook:GUID and that GUID exists locally Outlook will opend the requested mail.

Comment: I followed these steps http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-missing-outlook-protocol/ . My problem is that when i put "outlook:"+ GUID in my href in my visualforce page  i'm able to open only the outlook inbox, but not the selected mail. If i put an href in in a mail (in outlook) i can open the selected mail.

Comment: Did you somehow solve this issue, @FabrizioPugliese? I have exactly the same problem...